# Python: List Comprehension with a Nested Loop

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a situation where I am using list comprehension to scan one list and return items that match a certain criteria.

`[item for item in some_list_of_objects if 'thisstring' in item.id]`

I want to expand this and have a list of things that can be in the item, the list being of unknown length. Something like this:

`string_list = ['somestring', 'another_string', 'etc']`

`[item for item in some_list_of_objects if one of string_list in item.id]`

What is a pythonic way to accomplish this? I know I could easily rewrite it to use the standard loop structure, but I would like to keep the list comprehension if I can do so without producing very ugly code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly, I think your best bet is to use a loop.  It'll probably end up the cleanest in the long-run.

Comment: How big is your `string_list` in reality?

Comment: @StefanPochmann probably about 30. I'm breaking a DNA string into codons then doing translation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to solve this with a standard loop, it's not that hard, and much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
string_list = ['somestring', 'another_string', 'etc']

[item for item in some_list if any(s in item.id for s in string_list)]
```

any will *lazily evaluate* breaking on the first match or checking all if we don't get a match.

Comment: @AdamSmith, was my first thought but the OP wants to match also substrings based on their question, if the logic was  item.id in string_list then a set would work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham oh I didn't notice he was doing substring matching. I should read the question closer!

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should have clarified in my question. I'm working with DNA strings and I need to map codons to amino acids via a table of values.

Comment: Do you have a lot of data to process?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin `any` function for that

`[item for item in some_list if any(s in item for s in string)]`